# How to get a hidden Id to delete a record in a jQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables, hidden, delete-row

I have Edit and Delete buttons in my jQuery DataTable. The first column is a record ID column and is hidden.
I have event handlers for the Edit and Delete buttons.
Should I rather use the event handler for the DataTable click and tr function to get the id, or if using the button event handlers (preferable), how can I get the Id from the row? i.e. identify which row was clicked on?

```
 const dataTable = $('#personTable').DataTable({
        data: serializedObject,
        columns: [
            { data: 'ID', 'visible': false},  
            { data: 'TitleCode' },
            { data: 'TitleDetail' },
            { data: 'FirstName' },
            { data: 'LastName' },
            {data: null}
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 8, 
                data: 'ID',  //'<div class="btn-group" style="width:70px"> <button type="button"' +
                defaultContent: '<div class="floatRightClass" >' +
                        '<a class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-edit" title="Edit"> </a>' +
                        '<a class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-delete" title="Delete"> </a>' +
                    '</div>'
            },

        ]
    });

    $(".btn-delete").click(function (e)
    {
        var dtTable = $('#personTable').DataTable();
        var selectedRows = dtTable.rows('tr.selected');

        var id = selectedRows.data().toArray().map(function (row) { return row.id });
        console.log("id= " + ID);

        // or
        console.log("id= " + dataTable.rows('tr.selected').data().toArray().map(function(row){return row.ID}));


        // This works, but the row index is hardcoded
        alert("..." + dtTable.cells({ row: 0, column: 0 }).data()[0]);

        // Error: undefined
        selectedIndex = dtTable.row(this).data()[0];
        alert("Id = " + selectedIndex.ID);

    });

   $('#personTable tbody').on('click', '.btn-delete', function ()
    {
        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var rowindex = tr.index();

        alert("rowindex " + rowindex);

        // Get the value of the ID in the hidden column (col: 0)
        alert("..." + dataTable.cells({ row: rowindex, column: 0 }).data()[0]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `$('#personTable tbody').on('click', '.btn-edit2', function ()` I can get the index of the row and the hidden cell value orID for use in serverSide - Db - Processing.

Comment: When `visible: false` is applied, corresponding field is never turned into `<td>` element of the DOM, hence no way to access that from within `click` event listener.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following approach.

Essential part here is to use [`rows().remove()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().remove()) method (you don't need to have id's of the records you would like to delete).

However, if you wish to delete those records from your backend storage as well, you might do something like:

```
$('#delete').on('click', function() {
    const selectedRows = dataTable.rows('tr.selected');
    $.ajax(/* throw selected rows data (or particular properties) using selectedRows.data() */);
    selectedRows.remove().draw();
});
```

```js
//source data
const srcData = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Steve Rogers', title: 'Captain America'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Anthony Stark', title: 'Iron Man'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Peter Parker', title: 'Spider Man'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Bruce Banner', title: 'Halk'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Thor Odinsson', title: 'Thor'}
];
//data table initialization
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  data: srcData,
  dom: 't',
  columns: [
    {data: 'id', visible: false},
    {data: 'name', title: 'Name'},
 //append 'Edit'/'Delete' buttons to the rightmost edge of the cell
    {data: 'title', title: 'Title', render: cellData => cellData+'<button class="delete">Delete</button><button class="edit">Edit</button>'}
  ]
});
//delete button handler
$('#mytable').on('click', '.delete', function () {
 //grab parent <tr> node of the button, use it as 
 //a selector to throw its id into message and 
 //delete corresponding dataTable row
 const currentRow = dataTable.row($(this).closest('tr'));
 $('#msg').text(`Row id ${currentRow.data().id} (${currentRow.data().title}) was removed`);
 currentRow.remove().draw();
});
//edit button handler
$('#mytable').on('click', '.edit', function(){
 $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('editing');
 if($(this).closest('tr').hasClass('editing')) {
  //turn each table cell into input field
  [...$(this).closest('tr').find('td')].forEach(function(td, colindex){
   $(td).html(`<input value="${dataTable.cell(td).data()}"></input> ${colindex==this.length-1?'<button class="delete">Delete</button><button class="edit">Edit</button>':''}`)
  }, $(this).closest('tr').find('td'));
 }
 else {
  //grab input fields from within each cell and 
  //put their values into corresponding dataTable cell
  [...$(this).closest('tr').find('td')].forEach(function(td, colindex){
   const cellValue = $(td).find('input').val();
   dataTable.cell(td).data(cellValue);
   $(td).html(`${cellValue}${colindex==this.length-1?'<button class="delete">Delete</button><button class="edit">Edit</button>':''}`);
  }, $(this).closest('tr').find('td'));
  dataTable.draw();
 }
});
```

```css
td button {
 display: block;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html><html><head><script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></head><body><table id="mytable"></table><div id="msg"></div></body></html>
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when trying the above, on the event definition at '=>

Comment: Probably, you're using some browser without full-scale ES6 support (some Microsoft stuff, maybe). Fixed the code to avoid arrow syntax.

Comment: Using IE 11, yes. I also changed the code to same as yours. so no errors, But , how or where in that selectedRows object can I find some way of getting the 0th col (ID hidden column) and it's value. or just the Row Index). This object is large and very confusing. Thx

Comment: As being mentioned in the code snippet above, `selectedRows.data()` would return you source data (objects or arrays) for the selected rows.

Comment: So, if you really need those id's you may do `selectedRows.data().map(row => row.id)` if we stick to my example.

Comment: Now I get syntax error on the '=>' of map(row => row.id). IE11.

Comment: Well, you know the way out: `selectedRows.data().map(function(row){return row.id})`

Comment: Thx, I learn't something from that. But it returns an object, not the id.

Comment: `selectedRows.data().toArray().map(function(row){return row.id})` that should work

Comment: Thanks, had a look at your demo, Mine seems exactly the same as yours, but I get a 'nothing null no value. ( I use object not array binding if that changes the scenario).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191305/discussion-between-neal-rogers-and-ene).

Comment: @NealRogers: It somehow escaped my notice that you've been using individual row buttons. Howerver, I've adjusted my code to suit your case, so it might be helpful to whomever face the same issue.