# Get id of clicked row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using `"jquery": "^3.4.0"` and `DataTables 1.10.18`.

I am having the following table:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var table = $('.datatable-responsive').DataTable();
});

$("#edit-row").click(() => {
  var c = this.id
  console.log(c)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Global stylesheets -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- /global stylesheets -->
  <!-- Core JS files -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- /core JS files -->
  <!-- Load plugin -->
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <!-- /load plugin -->
  <!-- Theme JS files -->
  <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/js/plugins/sliders/ion_rangeslider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/js/plugins/ui/moment/moment_locales.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="navbar-top">
  <!-- Page content -->
  <div class="page-content pt-0">
    <!-- Default ordering -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table datatable-responsive dataTable" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Image</th>
              <th>Profile</th>
              <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>-2</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-success">Posted</span></td>
              <td>Awesome Post</td>
              <td><img src="./assets/img/baby.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
              <td>Joe</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="list-icons">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <a href="#" id="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>99</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-secondary">Queued</span></td>
              <td>Cool Post</td>
              <td><img src="./assets/img/diy.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
              <td>Brad</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="list-icons">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <a href="#" id="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-secondary">Queued</span></td>
              <td>Awesome Post</td>
              <td><img src="./assets/img/infographic.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
              <td>Tom</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="list-icons">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <a href="#" id="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- /default ordering -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to put a click listener on the clicked edit button.

However, I currently only get `undefined` back. Instead I would like to get the id within the first column back.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just use your code as example and make some changes in **jQuery**.

Please try this, hope this works for you.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    var table = $('.datatable-responsive').DataTable();

    $(document).on("click", "#edit-row", function(){
        console.log('Id : ', $(this).closest('.text-center').siblings('.sorting_1').text());
        alert('Id : '+ $(this).closest('.text-center').siblings('.sorting_1').text());
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Global stylesheets -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- /global stylesheets -->
    <!-- Core JS files -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- /core JS files -->
    <!-- Load plugin -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <!-- /load plugin -->
    <!-- Theme JS files -->
    <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/js/plugins/sliders/ion_rangeslider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/js/plugins/ui/moment/moment_locales.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="navbar-top">
    <!-- Page content -->
    <div class="page-content pt-0">
      <!-- Default ordering -->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <table class="table datatable-responsive dataTable" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Profile</th>
                <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>-2</td>
                <td><span class="badge badge-success">Posted</span></td>
                <td>Awesome Post</td>
                <td><img src="./assets/img/baby.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div class="list-icons">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                      </a>

                      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <a href="#" id="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>99</td>
                <td><span class="badge badge-secondary">Queued</span></td>
                <td>Cool Post</td>
                <td><img src="./assets/img/diy.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
                <td>Brad</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div class="list-icons">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                      </a>

                      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <a href="#" id="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td><span class="badge badge-secondary">Queued</span></td>
                <td>Awesome Post</td>
                <td><img src="./assets/img/infographic.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
                <td>Tom</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div class="list-icons">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                      </a>

                      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <a href="#" id="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!-- /default ordering -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using arrow functions that will change the scope of `this` to `window` so to reference the scope of the element, easiest way is to avoid arrow functions for those handlers and simply use traditional functions:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('.datatable-responsive').DataTable();
});

$("#edit-row").click(function() {
  var c = this.id
  console.log(c)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Global stylesheets -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- /global stylesheets -->
  <!-- Core JS files -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- /core JS files -->
  <!-- Load plugin -->
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <!-- /load plugin -->
  <!-- Theme JS files -->
  <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/js/plugins/sliders/ion_rangeslider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/js/plugins/ui/moment/moment_locales.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="navbar-top">
  <!-- Page content -->
  <div class="page-content pt-0">
    <!-- Default ordering -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table datatable-responsive dataTable" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Image</th>
              <th>Profile</th>
              <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>-2</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-success">Posted</span></td>
              <td>Awesome Post</td>
              <td><img src="./assets/img/baby.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
              <td>Joe</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="list-icons">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <a href="#" id="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>99</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-secondary">Queued</span></td>
              <td>Cool Post</td>
              <td><img src="./assets/img/diy.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
              <td>Brad</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="list-icons">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <a href="#" id="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-secondary">Queued</span></td>
              <td>Awesome Post</td>
              <td><img src="./assets/img/infographic.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
              <td>Tom</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="list-icons">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <a href="#" id="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- /default ordering -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

However, if you still want the arrow functions then pass a `event` parameter to the arrow function and get the element reference using `event.target`.

1. To get the `id` that you have in the first column you can find the closest table row then select the first table column to get that text value.
2. You need to use a class selector for all those rows instead of id selector `#edit-row` as `id` should be unique in the HTML page.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var table = $('.datatable-responsive').DataTable();
});

$(".edit-row").click((e) => {
  var c = e.target.id
  var hashId = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text().trim();
  console.log(hashId)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Global stylesheets -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- /global stylesheets -->
  <!-- Core JS files -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- /core JS files -->
  <!-- Load plugin -->
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <!-- /load plugin -->
  <!-- Theme JS files -->
  <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/js/plugins/sliders/ion_rangeslider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/js/plugins/ui/moment/moment_locales.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="navbar-top">
  <!-- Page content -->
  <div class="page-content pt-0">
    <!-- Default ordering -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table datatable-responsive dataTable" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Image</th>
              <th>Profile</th>
              <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>-2</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-success">Posted</span></td>
              <td>Awesome Post</td>
              <td><img src="./assets/img/baby.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
              <td>Joe</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="list-icons">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <a href="#" class="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>99</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-secondary">Queued</span></td>
              <td>Cool Post</td>
              <td><img src="./assets/img/diy.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
              <td>Brad</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="list-icons">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <a href="#" class="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-secondary">Queued</span></td>
              <td>Awesome Post</td>
              <td><img src="./assets/img/infographic.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
              <td>Tom</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="list-icons">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <a href="#" class="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- /default ordering -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! Any suggestions how to get the id - which is in the first column - if I click on edit?

Answer (score 2):

The `this` in the click handler was pointing to the global `Window` object because you were using arrow function, change it to a regular callback and it will work as expected.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915875/javascript-arrow-functions-this-in-event-handler) for more information.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var table = $('.datatable-responsive').DataTable();
});

$("#edit-row").click(function(event) {
  var c = this.id;
  console.log(c)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Global stylesheets -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- /global stylesheets -->
  <!-- Core JS files -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- /core JS files -->
  <!-- Load plugin -->
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <!-- /load plugin -->
  <!-- Theme JS files -->
  <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/js/plugins/sliders/ion_rangeslider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/js/plugins/ui/moment/moment_locales.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="navbar-top">
  <!-- Page content -->
  <div class="page-content pt-0">
    <!-- Default ordering -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table datatable-responsive dataTable" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Image</th>
              <th>Profile</th>
              <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>-2</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-success">Posted</span></td>
              <td>Awesome Post</td>
              <td><img src="./assets/img/baby.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
              <td>Joe</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="list-icons">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <a href="#" id="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>99</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-secondary">Queued</span></td>
              <td>Cool Post</td>
              <td><img src="./assets/img/diy.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
              <td>Brad</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="list-icons">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <a href="#" id="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-secondary">Queued</span></td>
              <td>Awesome Post</td>
              <td><img src="./assets/img/infographic.jpg" alt="" srcset="" style='width:20%;'></td>
              <td>Tom</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="list-icons">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <a href="#" id="edit-row" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-bin"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- /default ordering -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

DataTables has own solution, you can use [select extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) to get selected row data, there is an [example](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html) very useful for you

Answer (score 1):

Considering your ultimate goal (editable DataTable), I'll allow myself to suggest few improvements to your app, so that you **don't** really need to get id of clicked row and do all the HTML heavy lifting on your own.

- Instead of using external AJAX-call to populate your DataTables, I'd recommend to use embedded [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option

```
$("#posts").DataTable({
    //specify URL for AJAX-call that retrieves table data in format of array of arrays or array of objects
    //where each element/property corresponds to table columns, ajax.dataSrc property should be set to ''
    //if data array encompassed into 'data' property (default format), 'dataSrc' can be ommitted
    ...
    ajax: {
      url: "/getdata"
      dataSrc: ''
    }
})
```

- use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to modify cell contents, to make it appear as a  badge or drop-down menu

```
dataTable = $("#posts").DataTable({
    ...
    columns: [
      { data: "id", title: "Id" },
      {
        data: "status",
        title: "Status",
        //render status as a badge, having class, based on status value
        render: data => `<span class="badge ${data == "posted" ? "badge-success" : "badge-secondary"}">${data}</span>`
      }
      ...
    ]
})
```

- and **essential** point - leave row number mark within dropdown element upon rendering, so you can access this value later on as you need to edit/delete table row

```
$("#posts").DataTable({
    ...
    columns: [
      ...
      {
        data: null,
        title: "Actions",
        //render 'Actions' column as a drop-down menu wrapper,
        //appending 'row' attribute with corresponding row number
        //as a value
        render: (data, type, row, meta) => `
        <div class="dropdown" row="${meta.row}">
        <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item edit-row"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>Edit</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item delete-row"><i class="icon-bin"></i>Delete</a>
        </div>
      </div>
        `
      }
    ]
});
```

- use above row numbers in order to modify target table row, using DataTables API methods (e.g. [`row().remove()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()) for deletion), I'll use simplest example (deletion of the row in the front-end), since you didn't share much details as for whether you want to modify both back end and front end data or only the latter

```
//delete-row callback as an example of how to use row attribute to modify necessary table row
$("#posts").on("click", ".delete-row", function () {
    //grab dropdown wrapper and obtain row number
    const rowNumber = $(this)
        .closest(".dropdown")
        .attr("row");
    //delete corresponding table row and re-draw the table
    dataTable.row(rowNumber).remove();
    dataTable.draw();
});
```

Complete working **DEMO** of your sample project can be found [over here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jxlq54ol5?fontsize=14) or you can examine that demo in your browser's Dev Tools, using this [link](https://jxlq54ol5.sse.codesandbox.io/).

*P.S.* if, for some reason, you still decide to proceed with your approach, you may inquiry [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55529368/how-to-get-a-hidden-id-to-delete-a-record-in-a-jquery-datatable/55529844#55529844) post (which is pretty similar to yours) for a way of getting data model properties ('id', in particular) of clicked row