# How to Dynamically Add Edit/Delete Buttons for each row in a HTML table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datatables

I have a SQL table that I'm using to populate a table, and I want to add 'Delete' and 'Edit' Buttons to the row.

I have an input textbox corresponding to a column in my sql table, "PartNo". I currently have two functions: BuildTable and GetData, both a called when a button is pushed. GetData() makes the connection with the sql database and queries for data with the user specified PartNo, and BuildTable uses a StringBuilder class to create an html table and populate it with the sql data. I want each row to have a delete and edit button for which can delete and edit that specific row.

```cs
protected void BuildTable(Datatable dt){
//Building an HTML string;
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.Append("<h3><b>Parts Location Details</b></h3>");
        //table start
        html.Append("<table align='center' bgcolor='#dbdbdb'>");

        //Building the Header row.
        html.Append("<tr >");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<th style='color: white' bgcolor='darkblue'>");
            html.Append(column.ColumnName);
            html.Append("</th>");
        }
        html.Append("<th style ='color:white' bgcolor ='blue'>Edit</th>");
        html.Append("<th style ='color:white' bgcolor ='blue'>Delete</th>");
        html.Append("<th style ='color:white' bgcolor ='blue'>Print</th>");
        html.Append("<tr>");

        //building the data row
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            countRows++;
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");
            }
            html.Append("<td><input type='button' value='Edit'/></td>");
            html.Append("<td><input type='button' value='Delete' runat='server' onclick='btndelete_Click'/></td>");
            //html.Append("<td><asp:button ID='delete' runat='server' Text='Delete' OnClick='btndelete'/></td>");
            html.Append("<td><input type='button' value='Print'/></td>");
            html.Append("</tr>");
        }
        //table end
        html.Append("</table>");

        //append the HTML string to PlaceHolder with ID=spDetailsNew
        spDetailsNew.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
}
```

I have tried using a regular html input button and an asp:button object; the asp:button object doesn't show on the table, and the input button's 'onclick' function isn't called when it's clicked. I haven't coded the Delete onclick function yet; it's just supposed to give an alert that the Delete button has been pushed, and it's not doing that.

Comment: as is, you have no markup defining each row.  You should consider using a viewmodel and datamodel here.  Data bound to the page controller.  You can then use each row's UID for the script call in the edit/delete button.  (Using the type of markup Thomas described below.) Or just create text links which pass the IDs to another page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery datatable edit table row data using form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591938/jquery-datatable-edit-table-row-data-using-form)

Answer (score 0):

why you don't build your table with razor ?
 - create a customObject to store your data
 - create a view and pass your object 
 - on your cshtml

```
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in items)
        {
            <td>@item.something</td>
        }
    </tr>
...
```

If you don't want use razor, you should write some javascript and attach to the onclick="javascriptFunction()".
And on the stringbuilder add the javascript :

```
<script> javascriptFunction() { /** code here */ } </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas said, it'll be easier to use an MVC approach.  here's an example of how I use razor style markup (using "HTMLHelpers") for edit/details/delete links:

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.BOMs)
    {
       <tr>
        <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BOMItem.InternalPN)
       </td>
       //  other cells....
    <td nowrap="">
                <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.BOMItem.ID"
                   asp-route-limit="@Model.CurrentLimit"
                   asp-route-pageIndex="@Model.CurrentPageIndex"
                   asp-route-SortOrder="@Model.CurrentSort"
                   asp-route-SortDir="@Model.CurrentSortDir"
                   asp-route-ViewMode="@Model.CurrentViewMode">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.BOMItem.ID"
                   asp-route-limit="@Model.CurrentLimit"
                   asp-route-pageIndex="@Model.CurrentPageIndex"
                   asp-route-SortOrder="@Model.CurrentSort"
                   asp-route-SortDir="@Model.CurrentSortDir"
                   asp-route-ViewMode="@Model.CurrentViewMode">Details</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.BOMItem.ID" asp-route-KitID="@Model.CurrentKitID"
                   asp-route-limit="@Model.CurrentLimit"
                   asp-route-pageIndex="@Model.CurrentPageIndex"
                   asp-route-SortOrder="@Model.CurrentSort"
                   asp-route-SortDir="@Model.CurrentSortDir"
                   asp-route-ViewMode="@Model.CurrentViewMode">Delete</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
    }
```

The "asp-page" parts set which page the data is sent to.  The "asp-route-" part defines variables which are bound to the controller (page_name.cs).  You'll see the "asp-route-id" value is set to "@item.BOMItem.ID" which is a part of the viewmodel and corresponds to the datamodel's UID.  The controller does the database lookup and creates the "BOMs" viewmodel.  (Ignore the other "asp-route-" variables, those are just view variables for the page.)  Here's a tutorial on Razor Pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio  If needed.  (It's just a sort of simplified framework for MVC... and is a good starting point for learning MVC.)